# How to add a logo for a payment method OTHER than PayPal

Tags: checkout, payment

similar to the PayPal logo at the checkout page, I would like to add a logo for Cash on Delivery and Bank Transfer. How to go about that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the form template being used (per payment method) by adding this code to your layout XML:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="checkout.payment.methods">
        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>cod</method><template>payment/form/cod.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>bank_transfer</method><template>payment/form/bank_transfer.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>

<checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>cod</method><template>payment/form/cod.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>bank_transfer</method><template>payment/form/bank_transfer.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
```

You may need to replace `cod` and `bank_transfer`, if the payment methods use a different code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add logo in payment methods file

refer this 
https://github.com/sudheerpal/MagentoPaymentMethodLogo

Comment: Welcome to SE. Single link answers are not the best answers. Please explain in a few words how the extension works and what it does.